# How to calculate the number of divisors in a list for a number in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, counting, factors, factorization

How to I create a function called numDivisors. The function is defined as (numDivisors n listOfNums) and it counts the number of integers in the list that divide n without any remainder.

Example of the function call
`(numDivisors 10 '(1 20 30 2 5 40 10 60))` 
returns 4 from (1 2 5 10)

Current code:

```
(define numDivisors
  (lambda (x lst)
    (cond
      ((null? lst) 0)
      ((eq? (remainder 10 (car lst)) 0) (+ 1 (numDivisors x (cdr lst))))
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: How to do this depends rather a lot on whether this is an exercise in using higher-order functions or in figuring out explicit recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is close.

First you need to change `eq?` to `=`, which tests equality of numbers, and change `(remainder 10 ...)` to `(remainder x ...)`, so that 10 is no longer hard-wired into your solution.

Second, you need to add a third clause to your `cond` to handle the case where the remainder is not 0. I'll let you think about that; given what you have done so far, I am confident you will figure it out.

And you should stack those three closing parentheses at the end of the last line of code instead of placing them on lines by themselves.

An experienced Scheme programmer would probably write:

```
(define (numDivisors n xs)
  (define (divides? d n) (zero? (modulo n d)))
  (length (filter (lambda (d) (divides? d n)) xs)))
```

If that makes no sense at all, you should probably wait a few weeks. I'm sure your instructor will soon have you writing code like that.

Comment: personally, I much prefer [lots and lots of whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2lo3.png). I realize this goes against the accepted LISP writing guidelines, but these are from long ago, perhaps too long. why should the language's keyword like `define` be on the same footing as the user chosen name, like a name of a function or an argument? why insist on having it all as a wall of words? perhaps my slight visual impairment is the reason for my preference, but I still think that way is easier to read. and I have a hunch it'll be much easier for the newbies. they insist on using (contd.)

Comment: ... separate lines for separate closing parens after all. consistently, through the years. well that one I of course do not propose. :) but more visual separation lets a reader ignore the noise (like the word `define`) and have the function name separated better  from its arguments... I mean visually, instead of having to do that mentally. Just a thought. :)